# Showing star rating on Oracle Apex Classic Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

Star ratings are now a built-in item type for oracle apex forms.

But how do you display them nicely on a report?  In particular on a classic report that is displaying cards.
Its not a built-in classic report column type.  Would this be easier with a different type of report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question pretty well documented here:  https://community.oracle.com/message/15550215#15550215

Namely the instructions:

1. Set the HTML Expression property on the RATING column to:

```html
<span class="fa u-hot-text report-star-rating" data-rating="#RATING#" title="#RATING#" aria-hidden-"true"></span>
<span class="u-VisuallyHidden">#RATING#</span>
```

Change the u-hot-text to another utility class (if needed) to vary the colour of the stars.

2. Add this style sheet to the Custom CSS section of the Theme Roller:

```css
.report-star-rating {  
  white-space: nowrap;  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="0"]::before {  
  content: "\f006\f006\f006\f006\f006";  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="1"]::before {  
  content: "\f005\f006\f006\f006\f006";  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="2"]::before {  
  content: "\f005\f005\f006\f006\f006";  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="3"]::before {  
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f006\f006";  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="4"]::before {  
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f006";  
}  
.report-star-rating[data-rating="5"]::before {  
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The star rating item type can only be used as a standalone form item or as a column in an interactive grid.

You cannot use it in a classic report or an interactive report out of the box - but it should be rather simple to just let your sql output the corresponding read only html, like this:

```
select
    '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-star"></span>'
as x from dual
union
select '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' as x from dual
```